# How to get the URL of a file in a document library using sp.web (SPFX)

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I need to get the URL of each individual files in a SharePoint library (Case Documents). At the moment I'm using:

```
sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Case Documents").items.get().then((items: any[]) => { 
      let returnedItems: IListCItem[] = items.map((item) => { return new ListCItem(item); });

      this.setState({ 

        ListCItems: returnedItems, 
      }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.ListCItems);
      });
    });


//     sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Case Documents").items.select("ID","Title","CaseID/Title","CaseID/ID").expand("CaseID").get().then((items: any[]) => { 
//       let returnedItems: IListCItem[] = items.map((item) => { return new ListCItem(item); });
//  console.log(returnedItems);
//       this.setState({ 

//         ListCItems: returnedItems, 
//       });
//     });
```

...to get the list of file names. I've struggled with getting lookup columns using the commented out code as you can see. I included that to show you how what I've used.

Can someone tell me how to get the URL of each file so I can then create clickable links for each document in the web part I'm creating.

I've looked at: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Files
but it's not clear to me. I'm guessing something like:

```
pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/dev/documents").files.getByName("file.txt").getText().then((text: string) => {});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample demo:

```
sp.web.lists.getByTitle('MyDoc2').items.select('Id,FileRef').get().then((items:any) => {      
      items.map((item)=>{       
        console.log(item.FileRef);       
      }) 
    })
```

Comment: This gives the exact URL, which is what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

You can even compose the URL by yourself.

```
[siteurl]/[document library name]/[file name with extension]
```

where you can get site url in spfx by:

```
this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl
```

you can pass this as a `prop` to your component from your `webpartname.ts` file

Comment: Hi Muhammad, that's great, what sp.web property/function would I use to incorporate that in order to return all items from the lib? Would it be getFileByServerRelativeUrl?

Comment: getFilebyServerRelativeUrl, retrieves a specific file, what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to make a clickable link in ListC, that opens the doc itself. At the moment I'm using:

Comment: private _openFile = (ev: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    const sid = Number(ev.currentTarget.id);
    let _item = this.state.ListCItems.filter((item) => { return item.Id === sid; });
    if(_item && _item.length >0) {
      console.log(sid);
    }
   
  }

Comment: btw to get all files names you could use something like
`sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Case Documents").items.select("FileLeafRef").get()`

Comment: and for the render:
<td style={{ width: '100px' }}><Link id={item.Id.toString()} onClick={this._openFile}>{item.Title}</Link></td>
Which gives an error....I've bound it to this...

Comment: you could simply create document url as suggested and push that in array along with other properties that you are getting e.g. ID, title, CaseIDObject, DocumentLink. then use that link in your render method in an anchor tag href property

Comment: Using ``` sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Case Documents").items.select("FileLeafRef").get()``` where is the URL of the file in all that JSON?

Comment: this should return you the file name, you can compose url the way i mentioned in my answer, or try returning `EncodedAbsUrl` for the url

Answer (score 0):

The column FileRef returns the file URL. In case of FileRef it should be passed to the expands in getItemsByCAMLQuery. Like the code:

```
const viewFields =  `
<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name='FileRef' />
    <FieldRef Name='ID' />
    <FieldRef Name='Title' />
</ViewFields>
`;

const queryOptions = `<QueryOptions><ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll'/>  </QueryOptions>`;
const camlQuery = '';

sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Documents')
.getItemsByCAMLQuery({
    ViewXml: `<View>${viewFields}${camlQuery}${queryOptions}</View>`
}, 'FileRef')
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.log);
```

Please note getItemsByCAMLQuery({
ViewXml: `<View>${viewFields}${camlQuery}${queryOptions}</View>`
}**, 'FileRef')**